# Should I add "rather" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, adverbs

Example:

> I wouldn't call what I feel happiness, but (rather) an ongoing acceptance of
>   unhappiness.

Should I include the word *rather*? (Or replace *but* with it?)

Comment: You can say it with "but" alone, with "rather" alone, or with "but rather".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can very well include "rather" in this sentence, with/without replacing "but".

"Rather" stands for "better" or "more" in comparative contexts like this. So you can use it wherever these words are applicable.

Comment: That is not the meaning of *rather* as used in the example.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning in your example for [***rather***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/rather) is sense 5:

> 5) on the contrary; quite conversely   ⇒ "not a help, rather a hindrance"

The meaning is similar to *but*, however using *but* tends to exclude the previous phrase.

> I told you not to do that, **but** you did it anyway.

When using *rather*, this exclusion is not so distinct.
You are not saying the first phrase is wrong, but that there might be some middle ground between them.